# Reorder Lines Based On Previous File Order Before Randomization

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following lines in `file1`:

```
line 1text
line 2text
line 3text
line 4text
line 5text
line 6text
line 7text
```

With the command `cat file1 | sort -R | head -4` I get the following in `file2`:

```
line 5text
line 1text
line 7text
line 2text
```

I would like to order the lines (not numerically, just the same order as `file1`) into the following `file3`:

```
line 1text
line 2text
line 5text
line 7text
```

The actual data doesn't have digits. Any easy way to do this? I was thinking of doing a grep and finding the first instance in a loop. But, I'm sure you experienced guys know an easier solution. Your positive input is highly appreciated.

Comment: could you number the lines before you shuffle and then resort based on line number?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't (due to how the data is being handled). The only other thing I was thinking is to grab every nth line based on the number of lines. So if it was 12 lines, it would take every 3rd line. Or, if it was 20 lines, it would take every 5th line.

Comment: so is the final goal to choose a random subsequence of file1? in that case,  `sort -R` seems like a bad way to start.

Comment: Why not just run through `sort` again after `head`?

Comment: @JamesWilcox, no that is just an option. This is an example. The actual file is a lot larger and more complex.

Comment: I think you should make it clear that by "sorting" you mean "bring in the same order as appeared in `file1`", but *not* "ordered lexicographically", even though the example very strongly suggests the latter.

Comment: @dawg not every line has digits. That's just the example for easy understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decorate with line numbers, select four random lines lines, sort by line number and remove the line numbers:

```
$ nl -b a file1 | shuf -n 4 | sort -n -k 1,1 | cut -f 2-
line 2text
line 5text
line 6text
line 7text
```

The `-b a` option to `nl` makes sure that also empty lines are numbered.

Notice that this loads all of `file1` into memory, as pointed out by [ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti). To avoid that (and as a generally smarter solution), we can use a different feature of (GNU) `shuf`: its `-i` option takes a number range and treats each number as a line. To get four random line numbers from an input file `file1`, we can use

```
shuf -n 4 -i 1-$(wc -l < file1)
```

Now, we have to print exactly these lines. Sed can do that; we just turn the output of the previous command into a sed script and run sed with `sed -n -f -`. All together:

```
shuf -n 4 -i 1-$(wc -l < file1) | sort -n | sed 's/$/p/;$s/p/{&;q}/' |
    sed -n -f - file1
```

- `sort -n` sorts the line numbers numerically. This isn't strictly needed, but if we know that the highest line number comes last, we can quit sed afterwards instead of reading the rest of the file for nothing.
- `sed 's/$/p/;$s/p/{&;q}/` appends `p` to each line. For the last line, we append `{p;q}` to stop processing the file.

  If the output from `sort` looks like

  ```
  27
  774
  670
  541
  ```

  then the sed command turns it into

  ```
  27p
  774p
  670p
  541{p;q}
  ```
- `sed -n -f - file1` processes `file1`, using the output of above sed command as the instructions for sed. `-n` suppresses output for the lines we don't want.

The command can be parametrized and put into a shell function, taking the file name and the number of lines to print as arguments:

```
randlines () {
    fname=$1
    nlines=$2

    shuf -n "$nlines" -i 1-$(wc -l < "$fname") | sort -n |
        sed 's/$/p/;$s/p/{&;q}/' | sed -n -f - "$fname"
}
```

to be used like

```
randlines file1 4
```

Comment: Note that `shuf` loads the entire file into memory, so may be problematic for very large files.

Comment: @ghoti Good point. I've added a solution that doesn't have to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: Very nice. Two more things I'll add: First, `nl` by itself will fail to number blank lines, so `nl -ba` or `cat -n` might be preferable. Second, if you have a list of random line numbers, pipe them into `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} FNR in a' - filename` to print just those lines. Awk is so much easier to read than sed. :)

Answer (score 1):

`cat` can add line numbers:

```
$ cat -n file
 1  line one
 2  line two
 3  line three
 4  line four
 5  line five
 6  line six
 7  line seven
 8  line eight
 9  line nine
```

So you can use that to [decorate, sort, undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
$ cat -n file | sort -R | head -4 | sort -n
```

You can also use `awk` to decorate with a random number and line index (if your `sort` lacks `-R` like on OS X):

```
$ awk '{print rand() "\t" FNR "\t" $0}' file | sort -n | head -4
0.152208    4   line four
0.173531    8   line eight
0.193475    6   line six
0.237788    1   line one
```

Then sort with the line numbers and remove the decoration (one or two columns depending if you use `cat` or `awk` to decorate):

```
$ awk '{print rand() "\t" FNR "\t" $0}' file | sort -n | head -4 | cut -f2- | sort -n | cut -f2-
line one
line four
line six
line eight
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution could be to sort whole file

```
sort file1 -o file2
```

to pick random lines on file2

```
shuf -n 4 file2 -o file3
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `shuf` creates the same result as `sort -R` and will not give me the same order as `file1`